# Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I am deploying a SOAP web service through Eclipse on Tomcat 7. But following exception is appearing and Server dont start. I have tried removing server and adding it again but this error persists. Any pointer please on this issue?

[image]

```
    Dec 12, 2019 3:28:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\Users\tahir.akram\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\tahir.akram\OneDrive - Accenture\Softwares\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64(1)\eclipse;;.
Dec 12, 2019 3:28:24 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:History_WS' did not find a matching property.
Dec 12, 2019 3:28:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 12, 2019 3:28:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 12, 2019 3:28:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 999 ms
Dec 12, 2019 3:28:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 12, 2019 3:28:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getUTF8String(ZipInputStream.java:317)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getFileName(ZipInputStream.java:436)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(ZipInputStream.java:255)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:82)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:65)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.getManifest(ExtensionValidator.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5015)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

Comment: Can you give any other information? This doesn't tell us much. Did you copy the entire stack trace for the error message shown in your post?

Comment: @EricGreen that's the complete stack trace which appeared on the console of Eclipse. Is there anything else I have to check and share?

Comment: Did this happen the first time you tried to start up this installation of Tomcat? Has it worked before? If so, at what point did it stop working?